# What is an SQL query for counting records that are existing more than once in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("students");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `st_table` (`St_id`,`Grade`) VALUES ('$id','$grade')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$query = "SELECT * from `st_table`";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; 
echo "<th>St_id</th><th>Grade</th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['St_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Grade'] . "</td></tr>"; 
                           }
```

This code adds values into a table both ID and Grade. I want another query that will be able to count how many As, Bs, Cs, etc. and OUTPUT it on an html table.

Comment: you need to provide the table structure and some data in the question.

Comment: can you create sqlfiddle?

Comment: what does your query returns. I think it should work correctly.

Comment: Nothing, actually. It does not work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Can you show some sample data please?

Answer (score 2):

Here, Your query is ok just group by `Grade` not `Grades`

```
"SELECT `Grade`, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `st_table` GROUP BY `Grade`";
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69c41/2)

**After edit**

The query i am mentioning should work for you, you can check fiddle for that as for as you modified code is concerned you have to change your table a bit since you are going to include `St_id` as well so make it 3 column and correspondingly change query too.

Comment: Do i simple just echo it? I am doing that after running the query against the database and it is only returning the letter "A" rather than a list of sort

Comment: i think you should first insert some record to your table, then it will return list. Plus echoing is enough for testing but in real case you might wana apply some markup probably css too.

Comment: Yeah sure, i just need to test it out and make it work. I have already created queries to insert data thus, there are data already in the database.

Comment: ok tell me what is problem here right now? do you get a single record result or what?

Comment: @shinji check sqlfiddle